# How do I debug Axios frontend POST (React) to backend express POST? Console shows request as POST and status 200

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, crud

Browser: Safari
Texteditor:  VS CODE
Frontend framework:  Reactjs
Backend setup:  Express.js

Problem:  I have an Axios post request on the front end after an onClick call event is triggered.  I am unable to debug the data being sent in the body and know why it isn't getting over to the backend.

The screenshots show the code:(not the breakpoints in red.  I am not sure where a good place to use `debugger;`

[image: React Frontend code for axios post]

This is the code for the onClick event

[image: button onclick function]

This is the Backend code running on express port 8000

[image: backend express running on port 8000]

This is a screenshot of safari and the form being submitted. In the console is the response.  As you can see it shows as post request type and status 200.  None of that data gets over to the backend SQL database.

[image: Browser showing console of response data]

Note in the screen above that the object is rendered several times.  That is because to get this code to show the results in the console I changed this function.
[image]

to this:(though according to react the above is the correct way and will only fire the function once when onclick event is triggered.  The below approach does not require an onclick event.

[image: changed function]

Below is the data showed when setting a breakpoint on all requests.  Note that it appears to be a GET request when it should be a POST

[image: screen shot of requestData]

Note this is a POST REQUEST.  This only happens when the onclick function is changed.
[image: POST Data request]

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.  I know I am close to figuring this out, however, I am still new to React and CRUD works with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your backend isn't  handling the request being made from the front-end. if you want to see the data, try doing this in your server. You need to handle the request your front-end is making before sending a response. The below code just destructures the request body so you don't have to write many lines of code. Once you click on the submit button, you should see that your front-end input is popping up on your back end console. You are currently trying to send an unhandled request. If you want to let's say send something to the front-end based on the request, you would do something like
`res.json({nameOfThing: valueOfTheThing"})` **AFTER** **HANDLING** **THE** **REQUEST**.

```js
app.post("/", (req, res)=>{
   const {email, name, question} = req.body
   console.log(`Your Email is ${email} and your name is ${name} and your ${question}`)
})
```

The data should appear in your console. I have actually written a blog on how to do stuff like this. Feel free to check it out. https://dev.to/gbudjeakp/how-to-connect-your-node-express-backend-with-your-react-front-end-post-610

Comment: Thanks Sebastian Gbudje.  That worked as intended.  Also thanks for the blog, that is very useful.